# SQL group by and sum on different tables/views

Tags: sql, join, view, relational-database, coalesce

I have 2 views, A and B:

```
+--------------+------------------+
| Field        | Type             |
+--------------+------------------+
| id           | int(11) unsigned |
| vat_perc     | numeric          |
| vat_amount   | numeric          |
| project_id   | numeric          |
| ...                             |
+--------------+------------------+
```

I want a third view C which should basically have a similar structure but in the vat_amount field should contain the sum of all vat_amounts grouped by vat_perc and project_id from the two previous views.

C:

```
+--------------+------------------+
| Field        | Type             |
+--------------+------------------+
| id           | int(11) unsigned |
| vat_perc     | numeric          |
| vat_amount   | numeric          |
| project_id   | numeric          |
| ...                             |
+--------------+------------------+
```

For example, let's say A contains

```
+--------------+------------------+------------------+
| project_id   | vat_perc         | vat_amount       |
+--------------+------------------+------------------+
|  1           |  4%              | 10               |                  
|  1           |  5%              | 15               |                  
|  2           |  5%              | 15               |                  
|  3           |  4%              | 10               |                  
|              |                  |                  |                  
+--------------+------------------+------------------+
```

and B contains

```
+--------------+------------------+------------------+
| project_id   | vat_perc         | vat_amount       |
+--------------+------------------+------------------+
|  3           |  5%              | 10               |                  
|  2           |  4%              | 15               |                  
|  2           |  5%              | 15               |                  
|  1           |  4%              | 15               |                  
|              |                  |                  |                  
+--------------+------------------+------------------+
```

Then table C should contain

```
+--------------+------------------+------------------+
| project_id   | vat_perc         | vat_amount       |
+--------------+------------------+------------------+      
|  1           |  4%              | 25               |     
|  1           |  5%              | 15               |                  
|  2           |  4%              | 15               |     
|  2           |  5%              | 30               |                 
|  3           |  4%              | 10               |       
|  3           |  5%              | 10               |            
|              |                  |                  |                  
+--------------+------------------+------------------+
```

(I hope I made this clear enough, if you want an expanded example I could of course make it 'bigger')

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

use view:

`CREATE VIEW C(project_id,vat_perc,vat_amount)
AS
WITH CTE as (
SELECT project_id,vat_perc,vat_amount FROM A
  UNION ALL
SELECT project_id,vat_perc,vat_amount FROM B)
SELECT project_id,vat_perc,SUM(vat_amount) AS vat_amount FROM CTE
GROUP BY project_id,vat_perc`

Then only select values 
SELECT * FROM C ORDER BY project_id

Answer (score 0):

use

> group by a.project_id ,a.vat_perc,b.project_id ,b.vat_perc

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve that using `union all` and `group by` like this :

```
SELECT project_id,
       vat_perc,
       Sum(vat_amount) vat_amount
FROM   (SELECT project_id,
               vat_perc,
               vat_amount
        FROM   tableA
        UNION ALL
        SELECT project_id,
               vat_perc,
               vat_amount
        FROM   tableB) t
GROUP  BY project_id,vat_perc
ORDER  BY project_id
```

`order by` clause can be removed if not needed.